# Which distro of linux to use for testing pages on my localhost to be hosted on Godaddy?

Tags: php, linux

I am currently running a website on Godaddy built with php and mysql. I will open the website up today to the general public.  Because of this, I will not want to test any new code directly on the website. I want to mirror the website on my personal computer to test any updates.

My hosting is linux, and my pc is windows.  After installing xampp I found the website has many errors on my machine because of windows.

So now I am going to install Linux on my machine.  I have no experience with Linux, so this should be a fun learning experience.

Do I need to use the same distro of linux that godaddy uses to get the same exact results from my code on my own machine, or will any old distro of linux work?

Also, are there any distros of linux that are more geared toward what I'm doing (mysql, php, local server testing) or are they all the same in this respect?

After some reading, I am thinking of using Fedora, unless there is something better for my specific task.

Comment: Fedora is good. Make sure you get SELinux configurations correct. You may also try CentOS

Comment: No, you don’t need to use the same distro as GoDaddy — the same versions of Apache, PHP and MySQL will probably be enough (or newer — not a lot breaks with time). Fedora’s fine.

Comment: This is where VirtualBox is useful: you can run it on Windows to replicate the LAMP stack on your host

Comment: I figured there was a work around, but I would like to try linux.  I've been using windows for years and want to try something new.  If I don't like linux though, I will try your work around.

Comment: You could also create a subdomain on your webhost and run a development instance there.   Something like test.mydomain.com.  Or you could download an instance of Turnkey Lamp and run it in vmware or virtualbox and configure it exactly like your godaddy host.  First option is easier if you are strapped for time.

Comment: PHP is designed to work cross-platform; there is very little in PHP that is OS-specific. I'd be interested to know what the errors are that you're getting under Windows, because the odds are that it's something you could (and should) fix.

Comment: There are some functions that do not work in xampp on windows.  Like money_format().  I have removed xampp so I do not remember what the other functions were, but there was atleast one other.

Comment: It is very much better to run the same OS which godaddy is using so you would get exact versions of lamp stack which would be very useful for your tests too.